# Rails Controller can't match the array value with string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I look into rails server log, `@profile` has the value, it's like `dropdown_cases"=>["basic"]`, but the IF condition as my code below `@profile == 'basic'` does not match in Rails Controller, as the output `doing basic` does not display, I do not know why.

Below is my code.

Views:

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'submit' do %>
```

corpus type:

```
<%= select_tag 'dropdown_cases[]', options_for_select([['Basic','basic'], ['Standard','standard'], ['Advanced','advanced']], 'basic') %></p>
```

Controller:

```
def submit
    @profile = params["dropdown_cases"]
    puts @profile
    if @profile == 'basic'
       puts "doing basic"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove those square brackets (`[]`) from the name of the `select_tag`.

With:

```
<%= select_tag 'dropdown_cases', options_for_select([['Basic','basic'],
['Standard','standard'], ['Advanced','advanced']], 'basic') %>
```

It should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

do you need a drop down in your views ... if so then look at my approach... in my case
i.ll take a boolean type status in my model
and will define a constant STATUS

Model

```
STATUS = [['active', true], ['Inactive', false]]
```

Controller

```
resources :user
```

Views

```
<div><%= f.label :status%>
  <%= f.select :status, options_for_select(User::STATUS) %></div>
```